# Should I use 2 Prototypes, or just 1?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a scoring system for my game. Here is my code, and I'm using it as a prototype. However, every time I try to call it in the main function, my program just crashes. I'm using 2 of these prototypes (score1 and score2) because I need 2 different scores. Should I just use one? It's a dice game that shoots 6 dice, and I want to assign each number a value.

```
int score1( void) {
int roll1[6];
int sum = 0;
int i;
sum = roll1[0]+ roll1[1]+ roll1[2]+ roll1[3]+ roll1[4]+ roll1[5];
if( roll1[0]==1) {
    roll1[0]=100;
}else if (roll1[0]== 5){
roll1[0]= 50;
}else if( (roll1[0]!=1) || ( roll1[0]!= 5) ){
    roll1[0]=0;
}
 if( roll1[1]==1) {
    roll1[1]=100;
}else if (roll1[1]== 5){
roll1[1] =  50;
}else if( (roll1[1]!=1) || ( roll1[1]!= 5) ){
    roll1[1] =  0;
}
 if( roll1[2]==1) {
    roll1[2] =  100;
}else if (roll1[2]== 5){
roll1[2] =  50;
}else if( (roll1[2]!=1) || ( roll1[2]!= 5) ){
    roll1[2] = 0;
} if( roll1[3]==1) {
    roll1[3] =100;
}else if (roll1[3]== 5){
roll1[3] = 50;
}else if( (roll1[3]!=1) || ( roll1[3]!= 5) ){
    roll1[3] = 0;
}
if( roll1[4]==1) {
    roll1[4] = 100;
}else if (roll1[4]== 5){
roll1[4] = 50;
}else if( (roll1[4]!=1) || ( roll1[4]!= 5) ){
   roll1[4] = 0;
} if( roll1[5]==1) {
    roll1[5] = 100;
}else if (roll1[5]== 5){
roll1[5] = 50;
}else if( (roll1[5]!=1) || ( roll1[5]!= 5) ){
    roll1[5] = 0;
}
if((roll1[i]==roll1[i+1]) && (roll1[i+1]==roll1[i+2])) {
    sum = (100*i)+roll1[i+3]+roll1[i+4]+roll1[i+5];
}
if((roll1[i]==roll1[i+1])&&(roll1[i+1]==roll1[i+2])&&(roll1[i+2]== roll1[i+3])) {
    sum = (2*(100*i))+roll1[i+4]+roll1[i+5];
}
if((roll1[i]==roll1[i+1])&&(roll1[i+1]==roll1[i+2])&&(roll1[i+2]== roll1[i+3])&&(roll1[i+3]==roll1[i+4])) {
    sum = (4*(100*i))+roll1[i+5];
}
if((roll1[i]==roll1[i+1])&& (roll1[i+1]==roll1[i+2])&&(roll1[i+2]== roll1[i+3])&& (roll1[i+3]==roll1[i+4])&& (roll1[i+4]== roll1[i+5])) {
    sum = 8*(100*i);
}
if((roll1[0]==1)&& (roll1[1]==2) && (roll1[2]==3)&& (roll1[3]==4)&& (roll1[4]== 5) && (roll1[5]==6)){
    sum = 1500;
}
return sum;
```

}

Comment: `just crashes` at which point, please? also, consider indenting your code

Comment: please format and indent your code properly when posting here. and please also consider before: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SouravGhosh, this isn't my entire code, but in the main, it crashes after it prints out the dice roll. I have 6 values that are from 1-6, but it crashes before it prints out the score. I didn't include my entire code due to it being over 300 lines.

Comment: our code is unreadable, please format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bam! Reading from uninitialized values will KILL you every time:

```
int roll1[6];
...
sum = roll1[0]+ roll1[1]+ roll1[2]+ roll1[3]+ roll1[4]+ roll1[5];
...
```

What are the values of `roll1[0]+...` at this point? The compiler doesn't know and flies off into `Undefined Behavior` - a crash is an option. Until the values for each of the elements in `roll1[6]` have been set, trying to read from one without a value is bad (you see the result).

Two things. **1.** **Always compile with warnings.** (`-Wall -Wextra`) at minimum. **2.** **Always initialize your variables**, to **zero** if you have no other initial value. The following will prevent the undefined behavior.

```
int roll1[6] = { 0 };
```

Comment: So I just move the sum until the values of roll[i] are defined?

Comment: Yep!  That will keep the crashes away. Also see the 2 notes I added. If you compile with warnings, you would have found the problem before you ran the program, and 2 (it's just good form `:)` You just have to fill the ones you access. If you fill `roll1[3]` early on, you are free to use it from the time it is filled. Even if `roll1[2]` hasn't been set yet. But, to use **all**, **all** must have values `:)`

Comment: On common systems this will produce a weird value but not crash, so I'd still suspect that OP has an error in code not posted

Comment: Wow, this helped! Though now it seems that my prototype just gives out 0 each time. It runs though! It's a start! Thank you!